# Extracting a *.tar.bz2 file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, ubuntu-14.04, bzip2

I always used to use this command to extract files from a bzip2 tar ball:

```
tar xjvf file.tar.bz2
```

But right now on Ubuntu 14.04, I get this error:

```
tar: Conflicting compression options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Did something change or is this a bug?

EDIT: I think there might be a bug.  I just tried running it through `bunzip2` first, and then extracting everything from the resulting tar ball, and got this:

```
$ tar xvf file.tar
tar (child): pbzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

EDIT2: This is what I get after installing `pbzip2`:

```
$ tar xf file.tar
pbzip2: producer_decompress: *ERROR: when reading bzip2 input stream
Terminator thread: premature exit requested - quitting...
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Are you sure someone hasn't aliased `tar` to `tar xz` or something like that?

Comment: Pretty certain.  I'm pretty paranoid about access on my machine, so it's rather locked down, but I ran `unalias tar` and got `bash: unalias: tar: not found` just to sure.

Comment: If the file were created with `-z`, you would get `bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file`

Comment: Notice that I got that error after running the original file through `bunzip2` and then running `tar xvf`, so the error doesn't even make sense.

Comment: The `pbzip2: cannot exec: no such file or directory` leads me to ask if bzip2 is even installed? `whereis bzip2` If it is not found, `sudo apt-get install bzip2`

Comment: @Bert See second edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to install `bsdtar`.  I don't know why the regular `tar` wasn't working, but I'm going to file a bug report.

Answer (score 8):

You must be combining the `-z` and `-j`  compression options. The first uses `gzip` the second uses `bzip`. The command `tar xjvf` will not give you that error.

Comment: I promise I'm not.  The command I use is exactly as I've shown it here.

Comment: What does the command `file file.tar.bz2` return?

Comment: `file file.tar.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k`

Answer (score 0):

install **bzip2** and then it should be working. for example in debian/ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

or in gentoo

```
emerge bzip2
```